# Fetch from Core Data all the time or keep all objects in memory?

Tags: swift, core-data

In my iOS application, I'm using several Core Data entities and store about 50 to 300 objects in each one of them. Instead of directly working with `NSManagedObjects`, I use custom classes like this:

```
class Device {

     var object: NSManagedObject?

     var isFavorite: Bool {

          didSet {

               object?.setValue(isFavorite, forKey: "isFavorite")

         }
     }    
}
```

In some views of the app, I only want objects with `isFavorite == true`, so I make an `NSFetchRequest` with a predicate in `ViewDidLoad`. In other views, I want all objects stored in the entity, so I make a new `NSFetchRequest`, but without predicate.

The thing is that this is not very efficient and leads to split second delays when presenting a view (because I fetch in `ViewDidLoad`). One solution to this would be asynchronous fetching, but I was wondering if there is a more efficient way.

Since I always need those same 2-3 entities but just with different predicates, does it make sense fetch all entities when the app loads, keep all objects in memory and loop through them in `ViewDidLoad` to remove the ones not needed in this view? At the moment I'm literally fetching in every single view (a total of 10-15), so working from memory seems like a good idea.

Any thoughts? Advice is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data fetch happens over 15 times for the same data, then its better to fetch it once and use it as and when needed. If it all your database values are changed at any point, you can make a db call and refresh your data.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I am however wondering if it is a good idea to loop through all objects and remove unused ones. This is essentially the same as using an NSPredicate, but isn't this much more resource-hungry?

Comment: I suggested this as the same data is being read over and over again on different ViewController. Try the following approach, I am pretty sure the lag you see when switching viewControllers should be solved.